# Inline server tags in Mono ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono

I have recently managed to make my ASP.NET MVC application run under Linux with the Mono runtime. The .aspx pages execute perfectly, including assignment inline server tags, eg:

> <%= "Some output" %>.

Unfortunately, it seems that those tags for simple code execution are not treated by the server. Here is an example:

> write if true

Regular ASP.NET will display "write if true" only if someBool is true. Mono will output the whole statement including the server tags.

I cannot find any documentation about that problem... can you help me?

Comment: Seems that it works for a variable declaration but not in the example I have given...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your example works correctly for me on Mono 2.4.2.3.

- What version of Mono are you using?
- Did you precompile your website on Windows?
- Is it inside a more complex code execution block?

Comment: I admit that this was an over simplification of the problem. In fact, I am starting to think that the problem happens when a tag spans on multiple lines...